# Custom TableViewCell height being ignored

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I previously used the following code for changing the size of my cells which use a custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 61;
}
```

However I've created a new one on a different view and the above code is never being called.

The `UITableViewCell` is actually a control on a more generic view however all the other similar methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` etc are

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the tableview to the object containing the above method? Showing some more code would help.

Comment: I have set the file owners delegate and datasource to the tableview on my view. I cant really show you the code as its all in Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set your class as the `delegate` for the table view, in addition to the `dataSource`. They are two separate protocols, and this is easy to overlook.

Comment: It is set to datasrouce and delegate already, I dont understand how didSelectRowAtIndexPath, cellForRowAtIndexPath etc work but this one doesnt

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thank you thank you thank you! Your answer still applies years later!

Comment: It's kinda weird... `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` **should** be part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, since it defines how to display cells, but it's part of the `UITableViewDelegate` one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed this as well

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can accomplish the same thing (I think) in IB by tweaking the values on the UITableView (not the UITableViewCell).

Answer (score 0):

heightForRowAtIndexPath is only a UITableView delegate method, not a UITableViewCell method.

So you'd have that code in your delegate class, not in the table cell code.

Comment: If it's never called how can you say it was in the right place?  Only your getCellContentView will ever be called, and that's not the right way to do what you are trying to do (you've basically created a UITableViewCell inside of a UITableViewCell for no reason!)